Joining dataframes and keeping one data column as main
I have four data frames
Df=


Roll  marks  grade  section 
> 123   45.    C.     A.    C
> 344   67.   B.     A.    D
> 442   90.   A.     B.    B
>  887   80.  A.     B.    B

Ds=
Roll  marks  stream  class city 
> 123.   40    SC     12     Kol
>  554   67.   Cc      11.  mum
>  663   99.   A.     10.   Kil
>  978   100.  A.     11.  Che

Dq=
Roll  teamcode  game  state 
123.     34     F      It
665.     56      C.   Ft
775   .  89     Y.   Ko
798.    . 66     Z.   Yt

Dv=
Marks  dress  Reason   car 
33.     Gold    fail    no
43.     Gold     pass   yes
55.   .  Gold     pass   yes
78.    . Gold     dict   no

I Need to merge/join the dataframes mainly on the first dataframe like
Df, Ds on roll and marks
Df,Dq on roll
Df , Dv on marks

All should be joined/merged together .
In the output the the first column Roll should contain data from
Df['roll'] only.
Like
Roll  marks  grade  section stream class
                                    city      
123   45.      A.     C
344   67.       A.    D
 442   90.      B.    B
 887   80.      B.    B

If the roll and marks is common in other df then it sould return the value present against column

What is Df,sq? This does not seem defined.

Your example output at the end is exactly equal to the first Df.

Yes the first df sould be intact and other data frames should be merged according to the condition and their columns should come with data.

pandas.merge

Pls help with the code bcz it's not returning exact output

@CoderG I suggest you update your question with the code you've tried and why it's not giving you the output that you want
